# What is causing a 'ValueError: could not convert string to float' in my Seaborn heatmap code?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to generate a heatmap of my own data to visualise the concentrations of different molecules under 3 different treatments. I've copied the txt version of my csv file below (please let me know if there's a more helpful way to attach my data):

```
Treatment   M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7  M8  
T1  0   100712.7382 19611.79491 63247.3583  35466.06231 157194.3284 11832.79026 6861.946316  
T1  0   112185.5885 16895.13263 62396.65806 33705.14184 153651.1401 12028.82602 7078.235623  
T1  0   100237.4583 11528.48183 45396.74258 24782.96008 126615.4614 8109.732126 4758.349327  
T2  3297.63304  151498.393  22061.73441 65770.64251 29060.31538 103815.8753 14050.73934 13638.18694  
T2  10650.9355  531644.1483 115286.0835 258387.9607 125442.0706 449450.4285 71197.92515 57876.5793  
T2  17243.39342 868278.7007 124357.2049 257303.2244 131599.715  417409.1853 61542.46806 57155.9273  
T3  7911.32408  530803.8166 296693.6927 574056.1244 206971.864  645336.6162 165990.3327 72562.90148  
T3  4850.6574   336106.2586 163661.1811 282240.7615 104398.2993 292721.6451 83013.26339 44631.16076  
T3  10118.705   558533.051  361098.7829 643086.8186 161013.5292 523834.0415 176131.0724 80771.78798
```

The first column, labelled `Treatment`, is the treatment column. Each treatment was tested 3 times. The remaining columns represent one molecule each. The concentration of that molecule in each sample is recorded, e.g. cell B2 contains the concentration of `M1` in replicate `T1` (the concentration is 0 in this case). I want the heatmap to be organised so the molecules are in rows and the treatments as the columns, with a separate column for each replicate (not an average for each treatment).

When I have plotted heatmaps for other datasets in the past, I have used the code below.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_F1 = pd.read_csv('matrix_for_so.csv')
df_F1_heatmap = df_F1.pivot(index="Treatment", columns=["M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 8))
ax.yaxis.labelpad = 15
ax.xaxis.labelpad = 10
sns.set(font_scale=1.2)
ax = sns.heatmap(df_F1, annot=True, fmt=".3f", linewidths=.5, cmap="crest") #square='true')

plt.xlabel('Oxidant', fontsize=20);
plt.ylabel('Isolate', fontsize=20);
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
#plt.savefig('F1_heatmap.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

However, I get this error with this dataset:

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_29292/572287124.py in <module>
      3 ax.xaxis.labelpad = 10
      4 sns.set(font_scale=1.2)
----> 5 ax = sns.heatmap(df_F1, annot=True, fmt=".3f", linewidths=.5, cmap="crest") #square='true')
      6 
      7 plt.xlabel('Oxidant', fontsize=20);

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     44             )
     45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
     47     return inner_f
     48 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in heatmap(data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt, annot_kws, linewidths, linecolor, cbar, cbar_kws, cbar_ax, square, xticklabels, yticklabels, mask, ax, **kwargs)
    538     """
    539     # Initialize the plotter object
--> 540     plotter = _HeatMapper(data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt,
    541                           annot_kws, cbar, cbar_kws, xticklabels,
    542                           yticklabels, mask)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in __init__(self, data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt, annot_kws, cbar, cbar_kws, xticklabels, yticklabels, mask)
    157 
    158         # Determine good default values for the colormapping
--> 159         self._determine_cmap_params(plot_data, vmin, vmax,
    160                                     cmap, center, robust)
    161 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in _determine_cmap_params(self, plot_data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust)
    191 
    192         # plot_data is a np.ma.array instance
--> 193         calc_data = plot_data.astype(float).filled(np.nan)
    194         if vmin is None:
    195             if robust:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'T1'
```

I've looked at previous similar questions, but they haven't helped me, including removing spaces. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I've reduced my dataset to make it easier to deal with.

Comment: It appears the `'Treatment'` is a column in `df_F1`, not in the index. Check your dataframe. The code does not match with the error. 1. `df = pd.read_csv('matrix_for_so.csv', sep='\\s+')` if the csv has spaced and not `,`, as shown in the OP. 2. `df_F1 = df.set_index('Treatment')` not `pivot`. And then it should work. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPMx0.png)

Comment: `df_F1 = pd.read_csv('matrix_for_so.csv', sep='\\s+', index_col=0)` or `sep=','`

Comment: Since the categories are repeated, they can be aggregated with `df_aggregated = df_F1.groupby(level=0).mean()`, and plotted with `sns.heatmap(data=df_aggregated, annot=True, fmt=".3f", linewidths=.5, cmap="crest", ax=ax)` [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDEpc.png).